# Cannot delete a file, since it is not found (Windows 10)

Tags: windows, windows-10, filesystems, cmd.exe

I'm having an issue deleting files that are "no longer located" in the location I am trying to remove them from. After some brief research, the classic solution seems to be using cmd to delete the files.

Despite this, however, I've found that the delete command does not remove the file. I've tried to rename the file and have had success with that, but after the file will still not delete.

The file does not posses an 8.3 short name, which seems top be the term used whenever others delete problem items. Please advise.

Comment: Do you see the file in explorer? do you see it in command prompt with the dir command? what is the filename you're trying to remove?

Comment: I can see it in both file explorer and the dir command. Currently the file is simply named "Trash", but I've also tried giving it names of varying lengths to create an 8.3 name.

Comment: What is the location of "Trash"? is it in the root of a folder? If so, it is likely one of Windows' special folders designated to allow the use of deleting files to the recycle bin. In commandprompt this folder would be named $RECYCLE.BIN. This special folder win windows will have a different name and can be renamed without actually renaming the folder itself.